# Azure Stream Analytics - long living calculation

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

I'm using Azure stream analytics for real-time analytics and I have a basic problem. I have a field which I would like to count the number of messages. 
The json is in the following format:

```
{ categoryId: 100, name: 'hello' }
```

I would like to see the number of count by category, so I assume that the query in Azure stream analytics should be:

```
    SELECT
    categoryId,
    count(*) as categoryCount
INTO
    categoriesCount
FROM
    categoriesInput
GROUP BY
    categoryId
```

The problem is that I have to add TumblingWindow or SlidingWindows to the group by clause. Is there a way to avoid that and have the calculation running indefinitely ? Also I need to make sure the output is written to the SQL server.

Comment: As you mentioned you need rollups to be time bound or else Stream Analytics will never return any rows since it will constantly be waiting for more rows to arrive.   Maybe output counts by category every 5 minutes and then do an additional rollup inside SQL Server? Tell us what you are trying to accomplish overall and then we can help direct you better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this update. I'm trying to have a real-time calculation that counts the number of appearances (count) of each categoryId. If I will output the results every 5 minutes than every time I read the data I will have to sum it all, and this is exactly what I'm trying to save by using azure stream analytics....

Comment: Hi are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

How about a sliding window with the length of "1". This way it would act like a pointer and everytime it changes you can do the calculation?

Hope this helps!

Mert